# Is it possible to manipulate message query(Inbox) in Android?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

Sorry if i am asking a stupid question .So what i really want to know is that.Is it possible to manipulate the query ,that we are used to get the messages in Android.To be more specific i need to display messages from a particular set of numbers in default message inbox. 
I know that we can access the contact list using contentprovider and manipulate it .But here i only wanted to prevent messages from black listed numbers being appearing in default message inbox.

If possible please guide me through .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use the ALertDialog.Builder...
try this code:

```
 var dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    dialogBuilder.SetTitle("Record Saved!");
                    dialogBuilder.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert);
                    dialogBuilder.SetMessage("Successfully Saved!");
                    dialogBuilder.SetNeutralButton("Confirm", (Sender, args) =>
                    {
                        StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));

                    });
                    dialogBuilder.Show();
```

Comment: .i think u misunderstood my question .message means not the alert but the **SMS**.Need to filter the message while going into INBOX of the SMS in android.Is there any way.sorry for the confusion.